# Pass the current element to custom filter in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to pass the current element of `ng-repeat` to a custom filter?

Somehow like this (HTML):

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="row in rows | myFilter:row:anotherArgument>{{row}}</li>
</ul>
```

and (Javascript):

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .filter('myFilter', function() {
        return function(items, item, arg) {
            // Do something here
        }
    });
```

The data I'm dealing with looks like this (simplified):

```
[
    {
        "id":"52d7d22867960cb905e1c5b3",
        "label":"Model A",
        "children":[
            {
                "id":"52d7d22967960cb905e1c5bf",
                "type":"Page",
                "label":"Sample Page A",
                "class":"page",
                "children":[...],
                "watched":false
            },
            {...},
            {
                "id":"52d7d22967960cb905e1c5bd",
                "label":"Page",
                "class":"type"
            }
        ],
        "class":"model",
        "watched":false
    },
    {...}
]
```

So basically I have a tree like structure and in the first layer, there may be one or more elements with `"class":"type"`. The nested data is handled by Nick Perkins' [angular-bootstrap-nav-tree](https://github.com/nickperkinslondon/angular-bootstrap-nav-tree) directive.
I want to only display the elements that have `"watched":true`. The problem is of course, that the elements of `"class":"type"`, don't have the `watched` attribute.

**tl;dr**
Filter out `"watched":false` but keep elements with `"class":"type"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not as you're using it, but there are ways to work with the rows as a whole and separately.

If you need to access the elements of your rows before the `ng-repeat` content, you should write the filter for the whole array:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="row in rows | myFilter:anotherArgument"> ... </li>
</ul>
```

Within the filter-definition just work with the whole array:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).filter('myFilter', function() {
  return function(items, anotherArgument) {
    // here you can access each argument as you like
    items.forEach(function(item) { 
      ...
    });
    return items;
  };
});
```

The main reason for this is that `row` does not exist until you iterate over the array and the array itself is the *result* of the whole *FilterChain*. Think of the array rather like this:

```
ng-repeat="row in (row | filter1 | filter2 | ...)"
```

But depending on the purpose of your `myFilter` you simply might want to apply that filter in the content of the repeat itself.

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="row in rows">
    {{row | myFilter:anotherArgument}}
  </li>
<ul>
```

In case you're using the first approach I'd recommend to prepare your array in the controller before you're passing it to the `ng-repeat`. The more complex the filter chain inside any binding (as `{{...}}`, `ng-bind` or `ng-repeat`) gets, the more has to be calculated within each digest cycle of angular. That may lead to slower applications.

*UPDATE* According to the updated question:

In your case I guess a custom filter may look like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).filter('mySpecificFilter', function() {
  return function(items) {
    return items.filter(function(element) {
      return element.watched || element['class'] === 'type';
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm actually trying to do all this inside the template for a 3rd party directive. Would I prepare the array inside the controller of the part of my app where the directive is called or would it make more sense to add the adjustments in the directive itself? (I have been changing the directive template anyway)

Comment: Would you mind to tell a little bit more about what you want to achive with your filter? Maybe there is an easy solution to this.

Comment: I added more details to the original question.

Comment: Updated my answer. If you're only after that combination (`watched` or `class == 'type'`) it should work, but you can of course adjust that with more custom arguments.
Just keep in mind that the return value of your custom filter is what you're working with in the `ng-repeat`.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong in just doing ?

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="row in rows">{{row | myFilter:anotherArgument}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The first argument of the filter is not particular wrong, but unnecessary, as the left side is passed to the filter as the first argument anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample:

Please note that the first argument of the filter is the "Data Source" ( the entire list). It is the purpose of the filter to filter the Data Source.

HTML Sample

```
<ul ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="row in friends |myFilter:2:5 ">{{row.name}}</li>
<ul>
```

Js App and filter creation

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.filter('myFilter', function() {
        return function(items, begin, end) {                                     

            return items.slice( begin, end);
        }
    });

function myCtrl($scope)
{    
    $scope.friends = [
      {name:'John', age:25, gender:'boy'},
      {name:'Jessie', age:30, gender:'girl'},
      {name:'Johanna', age:28, gender:'girl'},
      {name:'Joy', age:15, gender:'girl'},
      {name:'Mary', age:28, gender:'girl'},
      {name:'Peter', age:95, gender:'boy'},
      {name:'Sebastian', age:50, gender:'boy'},
      {name:'Erika', age:27, gender:'girl'},
      {name:'Patrick', age:40, gender:'boy'},
      {name:'Samantha', age:60, gender:'girl'}
    ];
}
```